# How does a websocket get configured after creation and connection

Tags: javascript, html, websocket

I'm looking at this code from a tutorial:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" >
    <title>WebSocket Test</title>
    <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
        var wsUri = "ws://localhost:8081";
        var output;

        function init(){
            output = document.getElementById("output");
            testWebSocket();
        }
        function testWebSocket(){

            websocket = new WebSocket(wsUri);



            websocket.onopen = onOpen;

            websocket.onclose = onClose;

            websocket.onmessage = onMessage;

            websocket.onerror = onError;

        }

        function onOpen(evt){
            writeToScreen("CONNECTED");
            doSend("WebSocket rocks");
        }

        function onClose(evt){
            writeToScreen("DISCONNECTED");
        }

        function onMessage(evt){
            writeToScreen('<span style="color: blue;">RESPONSE: ' + evt.data + '</span>');
            websocket.close();
        }

        function onError(evt){
            writeToScreen('<span style="color: red;">ERROR:</span> ' + evt.data);
        }

        function doSend(message){
            writeToScreen("SENT: " + message);
            websocket.send(message);
        }

        function writeToScreen(message){
            var pre = document.createElement("p");
            pre.style.wordWrap = "break-word";
            pre.innerHTML = message;
            output.appendChild(pre);
        }

        window.addEventListener("load", init, false);

    </script>
</head>
<body>
<h2>WebSocket Test</h2>
<div id="output"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

And I am puzzled at how the websocket is configured after creation. The way I see the steps is:

The websocket is created with new.
As part of the creation the connection is made. 
Then  the four on___ functions are added.
The means the onOpen function is attached to the web-socket AFTER the connection to the server which of course makes no sense.

I think the connection is made on creation as I don't see any connection or functional call to the websocket anywhere else. Is it possible the websocket object detects when functions are being assigned? I feel like my misunderstanding is probably around this. The tutorial does work too so it is not just a bad example. Any clarification would be greatly appreciated.

I tried commenting out the onOpen assignment and the onError assignment and the client still seemed to work supporting my theory that they aren't actually being used. However, I also commented out the onmessage assignment and the "CONNECTED" screen showed up indicating that onOpen is indeed used.